# How does snapshot listener (firestore) work in viewmodel lifecycle?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in Android development and Firestore integration. I've been working on an Android app using Kotlin, which allows users to discover other users located nearby. To achieve this, I've implemented geohashing and utilized Firestore's snapshot listener functionality. In my repository, I've created a function called **findNearbyUsers()** that handles this task. Here's how it's defined:

```
override suspend fun findNearbyUsers(
        userId: String,
        center: GeoLocation
    ): Flow<Response<List<LocationData>>> = callbackFlow {
        try {
            val nearbyUsers: MutableList<LocationData> = ArrayList()
            val listenerRegistrations = mutableListOf<ListenerRegistration>()

            val geoBounds = GeoFireUtils.getGeoHashQueryBounds(center, NEARBY_USERS_RADIUS)

            for (geoBlock in geoBounds) {
                val listener = firestore.collection(COLLECTION_LOCATION)
                    .orderBy("geoHash")
                    .startAt(geoBlock.startHash)
                    .endAt(geoBlock.endHash)
                    .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                        if (error != null){
                            trySend(Response.Error(error.localizedMessage)).isFailure
                        }
                        if (value != null){
                            for (potential in value.toObjects<LocationData>()){
                                if (potential.userId != userId){
                                    nearbyUsers.add(potential)
                                }
                            }
                            trySend(Response.Success(data = nearbyUsers)).isSuccess
                        }
                    }
                listenerRegistrations.add(listener)
            }

            awaitClose {
                listenerRegistrations.forEach {
                    it.remove()
                }
                close()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception){
            trySend(Response.Error(e.localizedMessage)).isFailure
        }
    }
```

The **Response** class is implemented as follows:

```
sealed class Response<out T>{
    object Loading: Response<Nothing>()

    data class Success<out T>(
        val data : T?
    ) : Response<T>()

    data class Error(
        val message : String
    ) : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

The documents in the collection **COLLECTION_LOCATION** contain the geohash, name and userId of an user.

In the viewmodel (used for the FindUserScreen) I have implemented the following function (where **currentLocation** contains the longitude/latitude of the current user location):

```
private fun findNearbyUser(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val geoCenter = GeoLocation(
            currentLocation?.latitude ?: 0.0,
            currentLocation?.longitude ?: 0.0
        )

        repository.findNearbyUsers(userId = userId, center = geoCenter)
            .onEach { response ->
                when(response) {
                    is Response.Loading -> {}
                    is Response.Error -> {
                        handleException(customMessage = response.message)
                    }
                    is Response.Success -> {
                        _nearbyUsers.value = response.data!!
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

Once the user grants location permission, the **findNearbyUsers()** function is triggered, displaying nearby users to the user. This functionality is working as expected, and the live updates are functioning properly as well. Nevertheless, I do have a question:

Let's consider a scenario where the snapshot listener initially returns 10 nearby users, resulting in 10 database reads. When the user navigates to a different screen, the snapshot listener is removed. Subsequently, when the user returns to the original screen, the **findNearbyUsers()** function is invoked once more, reactivating the snapshot listener. If no changes have occurred, the user sees the same 10 nearby users. How would firebase count the reads in this case? 10 (one for each returned document) or only 1 for re-starting the listener? If it counts 10 reads, is there a way to re-initializing the snapshot listener by using the already downloaded documents?

I attempted to discern how Firebase counts the reads in my particular scenario by closely monitoring the live data reads. Unfortunately, my observations did not yield a definitive understanding of Firebase's read counting mechanism in this context.

I'm new here, so if something is unclear to you or if I made some mistakes, please let me know. I'm grateful for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.